# css bottom align

Tags: css

I have web pages on http://rygol.cz/qlife/ and when I zoom out, the id="contacts" goes anywhere every iteration when I zoom out. I need something like

```
border: 0;
```

Because I need that text of  will be every of bottom of 
any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To align a div at the bottom of the content add {position: relative;} to the content div and {position: absolute; bottom: 26px;} to the div you want to align.

CSS:

```
#content-wrapper {
position: relative;
}

#leftcolumn {
padding-bottom: 110px; /* this will prevent the normal content in the left column to go under the aligned div */
}

#contacts {
margin-top: 0;
position: absolute;
bottom: 26px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NMDCF/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to validate your HTML by using the following link : [HTML Validation](http://validator.w3.org/)
try to fix those errors before trying to fix your `id="contact"`

as for the `id="contact"` use `position:absolute` or `position:relative;` that may solve your problem. if that did not work, use this `display:block;` or `display:inline-block;` both could help you achieve your goals.